# Is it possible for a web server to respond to a HTTP request with an extended time stream of output?

Tags: php, apache, http, stdout

When you run PHP scripts in the console, all the standard output text from that script shows up in the console window while the script is running. Is it possible for a browser window to similarly receive status reports in the browser while a lengthy PHP script is running, instead of getting all the output dumped at the conclusion of the script?

Comment: Sure, just have the script turn off output buffering, then output status messages periodically. As long as the server doesn't override the buffer flushing requests, you'll see those messages show up in the client. But... at best the buffer flushes/overrides are only a SUGGESTION to the server and underlying OS that the buffers should be flushed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just call flush() and ob_flush() periodically.  It's important to write some output at least every 120 seconds to keep the connection to the browser alive.

A rough example:

```
    while(!$done) {
        //doWork();
        echo number_format(100 * ($workDone/$workTotal)) . "% ";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }
```

Edit: here's an arbitrary proof of concept that works in my env:

```
print('hello');
print(str_repeat(".\n", 2048));
flush();
//this might be a safe way to only flush the buffer if necessary?
if(ob_get_length())
    ob_flush();
sleep(60);
```

Comment: Didn't work. In [this](http://pastebin.com/LzeTUnzi) code I call [this](http://pastebin.com/27qkdkYD) function before the load starts, so shouldn't the user see this text as soon as the browser loads the address?

Comment: Curiously enough, I tried some simple examples, and it seems like Google Chrome only starts displaying output after receiving at least one newline (the man page for flush() also mentions some browsers requiring at least 256 bytes of data before they'll display).  Try adding a newline (and maybe some padding) to your echo before the flush.

Comment: I'd say Chrome also has the 256 byte requirement. The only case it output anything was when I received a lengthy warning on `ob_flush` not doing anything.

Comment: re: ob_flush() throwing errors, looks like one approach might be only flushing the buffer if it's not empty.  I'll edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one thing you'll need to worry about if you have a particularly long execution time is timing out.  This can occur as a PHP timeout or as a browser timeout (generally about 2 minutes).

This PHP documentation about [connection handling](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) has quite a bit of good information about keeping connections alive.